# Axis numbers overlapping. Any way to reduce the amount of ticks?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, axis

Just want to solve this problem, don't need any fancy solution for now, just reducing the amount of ticks should be enough, but couldn't get any close after looking for a while in the PGF manual.
There's any axis option that can be tweaked to change this?
[image]

```
  %preamble \usepackage{pgfplots} \pgfplotsset{width=10cm,compat=1.18}

        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}[
                grid,
                color = black,
                axis y line = middle,
                axis x line = bottom,
                xlabel=$x$,
                ylabel=$y$,
            ]
                \addplot[
                    domain = 0:0.15,
                    color = blue!50,
                    line width = 2pt,
                ]
                {0.5*(1-e^(-0.2))*e^((x-0.1)/0.1)};
            \end{axis}
            \end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Please, always post a complete compilable code, [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that). so people can quick copy and paste your code, not needing to edit or guess this or that package or command.
`x ticks` and `y ticks` are a start point, see [pgfplots manual](https://ctan.dcc.uchile.cl/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgfplots/doc/pgfplots.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

Using `xtick={<start value>,<next element>,...,<end value>},`, same for `ytick`. The increment is automatically calculate. You may also specify all values: `ytick={<y1>,<y2>,<y3>},` as I did as example for `ytick`.

A MWE follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots} \pgfplotsset{width=10cm,compat=1.18}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
      grid,
      color = black,
      axis y line = middle,
      axis x line = bottom,
      xlabel=$x$,
      ylabel=$y$,
      xtick={0,0.03,...,0.15},
      ytick={0,0.03,0.05, 0.10,0.12,0.14}
    ]
    \addplot[
      domain = 0:0.16,
      color = blue!50,
      line width = 2pt,
    ]
    {0.5*(1-e^(-0.2))*e^((x-0.1)/0.1)};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the distance between ticks with `xtick distance`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=10cm,compat=1.18}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        grid,
        color = black,
        axis y line = middle,
        axis x line = bottom,
        xlabel=$x$,
        ylabel=$y$,
        xtick distance=0.03
    ]
        \addplot[
            domain = 0:0.15,
            color = blue!50,
            line width = 2pt,
        ]
        {0.5*(1-e^(-0.2))*e^((x-0.1)/0.1)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]